# Can't start mysql service, force recovery is not working

Tags: mysql, innodb

Due to some hardware issues one of our database faulted and even using force recovery is not able to start it back up. The error I see on our logs is:

> Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 40160211114
>
> Error: trying to access page number 4293806975 in space 0, space name
> ./ibdata1, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len
> 16384, i/o type 10.
>
> If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf
> matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.

Will reinstalling mysql lose my data?

Comment: It's time to restore from the most recent backup. That really seems like the central tablespace is corrupted. You could try to engage a professional data recovery expert like https://twindb.com but I expect they will tell you the same thing: You have _already_ lost your data.

Comment: You'll find a better pool of expertise at [dba.se]

Comment: Thanks Bill! This looks like a corruption in the system table space (ibadat1). Now all depends on your luck. I'm pretty sure I already answered a question like that, try to search it here. Otherwise, check out https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/

Comment: thank you, ill check out the link.